# How to increase Emotion Detection Validation Accuracy on VGG16 model ? [Transfer Learning]

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, tf.keras, face-recognition, transfer-learning

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image

trdata = ImageDataGenerator()
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="path",target_size=(224,224))
tsdata = ImageDataGenerator()
testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory="path", target_size=(224,224))

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
vggmodel = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

vggmodel.summary()

for layers in (vggmodel.layers)[:19]:
    print(layers)
    layers.trainable = False

#flatten_out = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten()(vggmodel.output)
#fc1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(units=4096,activation="relu")(flatten_out)
#fc2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(units=4096,activation="relu")(fc1)
#fc3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(units=256,activation="relu")(fc2)
#predictions = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax")(fc3)
X= vggmodel.layers[-2].output
predictions = Dense(units=3, activation="softmax")(X)
model_final = Model(vggmodel.input, predictions)

model_final.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])

model_final.summary()

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, TensorBoard, EarlyStopping

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=40, verbose=1, mode='auto')


model_final.fit_generator(generator= traindata, steps_per_epoch= 95, epochs= 100, validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=7, callbacks=[checkpoint,early])
```

i am classifying emotion in positive, negative and neutral.

i a, using Vgg16 transfer learning model.

though i m still not getting better validation accuracy.
things i've tried:

1. increase the number of training data
2. layers.trainable=False/True
3. learning rate:0.0001,0.001,0.01
4. Activation function= relu/softmax
5. batch size= 64
6. optimizers= adam/sgd
7. loss fn= categoricalcrossentrpy / sparsecategoricalcrossentrpy
8. momentum =0.09 /0.9

also, i tried to change my dataset color to GRAY and somehow it gave better accuracy than previous COLOR IMAGE but it is still not satisfactory.
i also changed my code and add dropout layers but still no progress.

i tried with FER2013 dataset it was giving me pretty decent accuracy.

these are the results on the FER dataset:
accuracy: 0.9997  - val_accuracy: 0.7105

but on my own dataset(which is pretty good) validation accuracy is not increasing more than 66%.

what else can I do to increase val_accuracy?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is more complex than necessary. I would remove the fc1 and fc2 layers. I would include regularization in the fc3 layer. I would add a dropout layer after the fc3 . In your early stopping callback change patience to 4. I recommend you use the Keras callback Reduce  Learning rate on plateau. Full recommendations are in the code below

```
#flatten_out = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten()(vggmodel.output)
#fc3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu'))(flatten_out)
x=Dropout(rate=.4, seed=123)
#predictions = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax")(x)

rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor='val_loss', 
                                               factor=0.4,patience=2,
                                               verbose=0,   mode='auto')
callbacks=[rlronp, checkpoint, early]   

X= vggmodel.layers[-2].output
predictions = Dense(units=3, activation="softmax")(X)
model_final.fit_generator(generator= traindata, steps_per_epoch= 95, epochs= 100, validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=7, callbacks=callbacks)
```

I do not like VGG it is a very large model and is a bit old and slow. I think you will get better and faster result using EfficientNet models, EfficientNetB3 should work fine.
If you want to try that get rid of all code for VGG and use

```
lr=.001
img_size=(256,256)
base_model=tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.EfficientNetB3(include_top=False, 
          weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max')
base_model.trainable=True
x=base_model.output
x=BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 
                   0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.4, seed=123)(x)       
    output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(learning_rate=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics= 
                              ['accuracy'])
```

NOTE: EfficientNet models expect pixels in the range 0 to 255 so don't scale the pixels. Also note I make the base model trainable. They tell you NOT to do that but in many experiments I find training the base model from the outset leads to faster convergence and net lower validation loss.